# How to write SQL query for filtering the row which has two values for a column?

Tags: mysql, sql

Consider the table as below -

Table A

| Parent_Id | Child_Id | is_active |
| --- | --- | --- |
| P1 | C1 | Y |
| P1 | C2 | N |
| P2 | C3 | N |

Need the SQL query to identify the parent_id which has all child_id with 'N'.
In the above table the output should be

**Parent_Id**

P2

Comment: why P1 is not part of result since P1 is also having N ?

Comment: We need to show only those parent_ids where all child_ids have is_active as N

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sql
SELECT Parent_Id
FROM tableA
GROUP BY Parent_Id
HAVING !SUM(is_active = 'Y')
```

or

```sql
HAVING MAX(is_active) = 'N'
```

Comment: Thanks so much. This is working -                                                                                
SELECT Parent_Id FROM TableA GROUP BY Parent_Id HAVING MAX(is_active) = 'N';

Comment: @user10411549 Both variants must work. Maybe you loose `!` char in 1st variant?